# Как убрать валидатор в woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce

В `woocommerce` на странице корзины используются эти шорткоды:

`[woocommerce_cart]
[woocommerce_checkout]`
Применяю свой валидатор полей:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');
function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    if ( ! $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( "Заполните поле имя" ), 'error' );
    }
    if ( ! $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( "Заполните поле фамилия" ), 'error' );
    }
    ...
}
```

Если поля формы заполнены не все, то ошибка выводится дважды на одно поле: стандартная ошибка и ошибка из приведённого кода.
Как убрать стандартную валидацию?

**P.S.**
можно было конечно исправить перевод ошибки, но тут вопрос именно в том, как убрать валидацию

Comment: кто-то подскажет?

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "custom_my_fields");

   function custom_my_fields($fields) {

     $fields["billing"]["billing_last_name"]["required"] = false; // Фамилия не обязательна
     $fields["billing"]["billing_phone"]["required"] = true; // Телефон обязателен

return $fields;
```

//Вот полный перечень стандартных полей WooCommerce:

//Оплата:

```
$fields["billing"]["billing_first_name"]["required"]

$fields["billing"]["billing_last_name"]["required"]

$fields["billing"]["billing_company"]["required"]

$fields["billing"]["billing_address_1"]["required"]

$fields["billing"]["billing_address_2"]["required"]

$fields["billing"]["billing_city"]["required"]

$fields["billing"]["billing_postcode"]["required"]

$fields["billing"]["billing_country"]["required"]

$fields["billing"]["billing_state"]["required"]

$fields["billing"]["billing_email"]["required"]

$fields["billing"]["billing_phone"]["required"]
```

//Доставка

```
$fields["shipping"]["shipping_first_name"]["required"]

$fields["shipping"]["shipping_last_name"]["required"]

$fields["shipping"]["shipping_company"]["required"]

$fields["shipping"]["shipping_address_1"]["required"]

$fields["shipping"]["shipping_address_2"]["required"]

$fields["shipping"]["shipping_city"]["required"]

$fields["shipping"]["shipping_postcode"]["required"]

$fields["shipping"]["shipping_country"]["required"]

$fields["shipping"]["shipping_state"]["required"]
```

// Заказ

```
$fields["order"]["order_comments"]["required"]
```

Comment: если я установлю `false` в `required`, то ни свой валидатор, ни валидатор `woocommerce` не будет выводить ошибки.`$fields["billing"]["billing_last_name"]["required"] = false;`

Comment: нужно оставить `required` в `true`